# System.Management - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, system

```
private string Find(string key)
    {
        string result = null;
        try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity");
            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                if (queryObj["Caption"].ToString().Contains(key))
                {
                    result = queryObj["Caption"].ToString();
                    break;
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                                                                
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);                
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I Add Reference: System.Management to use this function to find a divice. It work it works on **Window 7**, but on **Window XP** have a error: **object reference not set to an instance of an object**

How to solve this error?

Comment: What line exactly throws the exception?

Comment: Well obviously windows 7 registry and windows xp registry are not identical..

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 3):

I was facing this issue in my earlier development years. The problem at hand is simple: The ManagementObject is throwing a `NullReferenceException`. The simple answer would be adding a simple checking for the properties:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity");
            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                if (queryObj["Caption"] != null)
                {
                    result = queryObj["Caption"].ToString();
                    break;
                }
```